# Android Studio not finding Android SDK on Fedora 28

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-sdk-tools, fedora-28

I'm trying to install Android Studio 3.1.2 on Fedora 28. It installs fine, and I've followed this as well: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development.

I do have an existing project that I'm trying to import, and it uses Gradle, but so far I've been unable to get it to recognize the SDK. "SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.".

Within the `local.properties file`, I have `sdk.dir=/home/USER/Android/Sdk` and the same path set as an ANDROID_HOME variable.

I can open the Android SDK settings, and it shows the location as the same path, and has Android 8.1, 8.0, and 6.0 all showing installed. I've tried creating virtual devices in Studio, and so far it's had to download the images, but both a Pixel 2 and Nexus 6 fail to boot with miscellaneous errors (code 134, interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT on the last attempt).

I am running a 1900x AMD CPU with virtualization enabled, and the only reason I've moved to Fedora is AMD virtualization through Android Studio is only supported on Linux.

Is there anyway to get this working, or is it more reliable on Ubuntu?

Comment: you have to select android SDK in the preferences to make it work

Comment: Those are set, and I've installed 8.0 and 6.0. The location there matches the Android_Home and sdk.dir settings. It randomly starts working, but this past time I had to redo the repo during troubleshooting it lost them so I'm back to being stuck.

Comment: Actually, figured out the problem. The existing project we're building from has a broken master branch so the initial pull doesn't work. Sheesh. Our branch fixes it, no idea why. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: congrats .. add it as answer and lets close this so other people having such a issue can move on ..